# How to show .Trash and hidden files on USB sticks but not in $HOME?

Tags: nautilus, privacy, usb-drive

In my home directory, there is a lot of [files beginning with a dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_files), and I like the fact that Nautilus hides them. But when Nautilus hides `.Trash` on a USB disk, I risk leaking confidential documents inadvertently, wrongly thinking that I deleted all files from the USB stick I give to an acquaintance.

So, how to set Nautilus to:

- Hide these files in my home
- But show them for USB sticks?

Another solution could be to disable Trash for USB sticks, but the idea is [not implemented yet](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/14871/).
Any alternative solution welcome. I am looking for a permanent solution, so hitting CTRL+H each time is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus doesn't support automatically changing settings based on the directory. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to manually toggle between showing or not showing hidden files (usually known as dotfiles), but Nautilus can't be configured to automatically toggle that option.

However, if you're using a filesystem on your flash drive that supports symlinks (not FAT32 or NTFS), you could work around your issue this way:

```
cd /path/to/your/flash/drive
ln -s .Trash Trash
```

This way, you'll have a non-hidden directory where you can easily check the contents of your trash.

Comment: Unfortunately the link trick is not usable, because the majority of USB sticks tends to be configured as FAT32 (especially those people lend to each other).

Comment: You're unfortunately correct. My flash drives must be usable on Windows machines. Grr.

Comment: Actually, I've heard that NTFS has something like symlinks. I haven't researched it, but perhaps you could reformat your flash drive as NTFS and use that trick. These days, NTFS is supported across all platforms.